# Applet connection to database JNLP error

Tags: java, sql-server, database, jdbc, applet

My applet connects to a database through jdbc. I get lots of this message when the applet tries to connect:

```
basic: JNLP2ClassLoader.findClass: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.? try again..
```

where ? is for example SQLServerConnection, or TDS

Any idea what might be causing the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may suggest your applet can't find a class which is supposed the JDBC lib must have. 
Anyway, you should create servlet to connect to your applet; As usual, servlets are using to access database and put data back to applet;

The project schema is something in this way: [applet <-> servlet <- database](http://onjava.com/onjava/2002/02/20/applets.html).